# Is the maximal complex subtorus in real torus dense?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, abelian-groups, abelian-varieties

Consider the torus $\mathbb R^3/\mathbb Z^3$. Then the maximal complex subgroup is $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$. Right?

Is $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ dense in $\mathbb R^3/\mathbb Z^3$?

Comment: It depends on your definitions, but in standard usage, a _complex torus_ is a product of $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ factors (the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers), and a real torus contains no "natural" complex torus. (On the other hand, a complex torus contains a real subtorus, the products of the unit circles.) In any case, $\mathbf{R}^{2}/\mathbf{Z}^{2}$ is not dense in $\mathbf{R}^{3}/\mathbf{Z}^{3}$.

Comment: I was reading about abelian complex groups that have no non-constant holomorphic functions. And I found a fact that an abelian group is so iff the maximal complex subgroup of a maximal compact subgroup is dense  in this maximal compact group. Where is the problem? What do you mean by "it depends on  you definitions"?

Comment: Or maybe the orbits of ($\mathbb R^3\cap i\mathbb R^3$) on the maximal compact subgroup who are dense?!